# Empty text labels in Kivy for Android

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am trying to implement this kivy example

http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helloworld/

The text labels in both the Button as well as the Label appear blank when I compile (on kivy's ubuntu vm) and run it on my android device (its Google Nexus 1).
The example however runs perfectly fine on my laptop.

How do I get around this issue and get the text to display?
Would appreciate any help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [bug #1192](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/1192) in the latest version 1.7.0, for phones that don't support power-of-two textures. I've changed how the textures are created, but missed one case.

The issue happen only on the phone with a crappy GPU :) Yes crappy, because OpenGL ES 2 specification says that power-of-two textures are mandatory. Guess what, Adreno 200 series (and maybe others) doesn't support them, but claim they are GLES 2.

Anyway, the bug has been fixed yesterday, and i'll release a new minor release in a day or two. If you compiled python-for-android yourself, just do:

```
cd python-for-android
git clean -dxf
git pull origin master
```

Then restart the compilation with ./distribute.sh ... It will works.

Comment: This was resolved quite some time back when I posted on the mailing lists. Thanks :)